# jQuery: get AJAX and confirm on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My goal is: When someone submits a form, AJAX is called, retrieves some GET result, then confirmation is prompted:

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {
    var messages = ... // get result from $.get() call
    return confirm("Confirm delete " + number + 'messages' ?);
});
```

I don't think promises will help in this case.
I can attach event and remove event: but this solution is quite heavy.

Any elegant way to do that?

Comment: where is your `$.get()` method?

Comment: Why don't you do the confirm in your success callback?

Comment: Why don't you think promises will help? `$.get(...).then(res => confirm("Confirm delete " + res.number + "messages?"));`

Comment: Than after the confirmation the form is supposed to submit? If yes, That is not going to happen with an asynchronous request.

Comment: Check @messerbill 's solution below. That is only if you don't want the default form submit behavior.

Comment: Since AJAX is asynchronous, you can't return a value depending on it, because it the response doesn't come until after your original function returns.

Comment: The message of the `confirm` depends on the result of the ajax get request? And after the confirm you want to decide of the form should be submitted or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get(myUrl).then(function(res) {
      confirm("Confirm delete " + number + 'messages' + res);
  });
});
```

you have to wait until the server sends the response to you using `.then()` method.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: and this will fail because the form submits

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('submit','#myForm',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
       type:'POST',
       data:{},
       success:function(response){
         console.log(response);
         var r = confirm("Press a button!");
         if (r == true) {
            txt = "You pressed OK!";
            } else {
            txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
           }
          console.log(txt);
       },
       error:function(error){
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="myForm">
<button type="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Problem is: this does not submit the form

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent the submit by default. And after the get request was received and the user confirmed the message you could remove thsi confirmation callback, and call `submit` on the form.

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get( )
  .then(() => {
     var messages = ... // get result from $.get() call
     if( confirm("Confirm delete " + number + 'messages' ?) ) {
        ('#form1').off('submit').submit()
     }
  })

});
```